# enter the US while waiting h1b

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, h1-visa

I am participating in the h1b lottery this year. I am currently outside the US working for a non-US company which had asked me to travel to the US in May for a business trip. Is there a real risk of immigration not letting me in to the US (thinking I try to start working for the US company)? I will come with documents to prove this is a short trip for my current non-US employer.

Comment: There's some related information in the answers to [this other question](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/1358/2037), but that one's about a tourist visit and a different timetable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Travel.SE